# sql query to count twitter comments by month in 2016

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list the number of Tweets made according to month in 2016. I am new to SQL but have tried different ways to do this. Below is my latest attempt. I keep getting a message that I am not using `datelogged` properly. Lastly, I am not sure of how to format `Total` and `Tweet_Cnt`.

The format of the date in Twitter is as follows: `MESSAGE_POSTED_TIME:  2015-08-06 21:48:34. FYI---- Column Name=MESSAGE_POSTED_TIME; Table Name=DTrumpCampaign_Tweets`

```sql
Select
    Year(DATELOGGED), 
    Sum(Case When Month(DATELOGGED) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) Jan,
    Sum(Case When Month(DATELOGGED) = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) Feb,
    Sum(Case When Month(DATELOGGED) = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End) Mar
From
    DTrumpCampaign_Tweets
Group By
    Year(DATELOGGED);
```

I would like for my table's format to look like this

```
Month(2016)     Tweet_Cnt   
Jan               25
Feb              100
Mar              200
total            325
```

I greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want data of only year `2016`? And do you want a row for each month OR a single row having all the months column alongside ?

Comment: Can I do it this way?  Select    count(*) 
FROM      DTrumpCampaign_Tweets
WHERE     year(ARR_DATE) = '2016' 
GROUP BY  month(ARR_DATE)

Comment: Yes I want data for only 2016 and a row for each month. I am getting an error message for your suggested query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am so new to this that I included some misinformation in my question. Datelogged should not have been in question because it is not the name of the column. I got this to work                        
 Select
    Year(Message_posted_time), 
    Sum(Case When Month(Message_posted_time) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) Jan,
    Sum(Case When Month(Message_posted_time) = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) Feb,
    Sum(Case When Month(Message_posted_time) = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End) Mar
From
    DTrumpCampaign_Tweets
Group By
    Year(Message_posted_time);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, with a sqlfiddle demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/786acb/5

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(`Month(2016)`, 'Total') AS `Month(2016)`, Tweet_cnt
FROM 
(
    Select
        DATE_FORMAT(datelogged, '%b') AS `Month(2016)`,
        COUNT(*) AS Tweet_cnt
    From dtrumpcampaign_tweets
    WHERE YEAR(datelogged) = '2016'
    Group BY `Month(2016)` WITH ROLLUP
) t;
```

The output is like:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| Month(2016) | Tweet_cnt |
+-------------+-----------+
| Feb         |         1 |
| Jan         |         2 |
| Mar         |         3 |
| Total       |         6 |
+-------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I tried it b'ut it didn't work. There are 3 errors.https://www.dropbox.com/s/96apfdblvod0zx0/Screenshot%202016-03-23%2010.48.49.png?dl=0  I never defined Tweet_cnt.

Comment: Update the ans, with a sqlfiddle link. pls try if it is as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am so new to this that I included some misinformation in my question. Datelogged should not have been in question because it is not the name of the column. I got this to work                        
 Select
    Year(Message_posted_time), 
    Sum(Case When Month(Message_posted_time) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) Jan,
    Sum(Case When Month(Message_posted_time) = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) Feb,
    Sum(Case When Month(Message_posted_time) = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End) Mar
From
    DTrumpCampaign_Tweets
Group By
    Year(Message_posted_time);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want data of year **2016** only.

---

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN t.`month` IS NULL THEN 'total'ELSE   t.monthName END) AS 'Month(2016)',
    t.Tweet_Cnt
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MONTHNAME(DATELOGGED) AS monthName,
            YEAR (DATELOGGED) `year`,
            MONTH (DATELOGGED) `month`,
            COUNT(*) Tweet_Cnt
        FROM DTrumpCampaign_Tweets
        WHERE   YEAR (DATELOGGED) = '2016'
        GROUP BY `year`,`month` WITH ROLLUP
        LIMIT 13
    ) t;
```

---

[**Demo with some sample data**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf2cb9/1/0)

---

You will get an output structure like below:

```
| Month(2016) | Tweet_Cnt |
|-------------|-----------|
|     January |         1 |
|    February |         2 |
|       March |         1 |
|       April |         1 |
|         May |         1 |
|        June |         1 |
|        July |         1 |
|      August |         1 |
|   September |         1 |
|     October |         1 |
|    November |         1 |
|    December |         1 |
|       total |        13 |
```

---

**More:**

If you want the month names having only first three letters only then just change the corresponding line in the above query as below:

**Change this line :** `SELECT MONTHNAME(DATELOGGED) AS monthName,`

**To this:** `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATELOGGED,"%b") AS monthName,`

---

[**Demo of this modified query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf2cb9/2/0)

---

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kase9ebe75zq8vf/Screenshot%202016-03-23%2011.11.28.png?dl=0  This didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked those demo I attached in my answer? May be the issue is in your editor. Try to change the column aliases and give that column name to something without single quote. Let me know then.@BonitaJWilliams

Comment: The screenshot you posted here is not my answer. Check my answer and let me know if it works for you.@BonitaJWilliams